# Moving a light switch without moving it

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, home-automation, rental

I live in a rented house, and there is a lightswitch which is unconventionally not next to the door in one of the rooms. Is there a way to move the lightswitch so it's next to the door. I am currently thinking of something that plugs in between the bulb and light switch that can be turned on or off wirelessly from a switch that can be stuck to the wall. Does such a thing exists? Or would leaving the main light switch always on and having a [remote controlled] switch in the light fitting cause problems?

Comment: Is the landlord involved, or are you restricted to a screw-in solution?  The options open up widely if you can change out the existing switch.

Comment: Yes I know, but we aren't allowed to screw into the wall and an electrical work would have to be done by a professional which is costly and too much effort.

Answer (score 1):

I did exactly that some years ago, replacing the light switch with an X10 remotely controllable switch, and hang the remote on the wall at the other end of the room. However, that approach will NOT work with LED bulbs, due to the way it powers itself, and may not work safely with fluorescents. (X10 is the low-budget brand which introduced carrier-current control signalling; there are better versions of the same system and alternative systems but they cost twice as much and require more planning in the house wiring.)

Remote-controllable devices do exist that screw in between the bulb and its socket. However, those obviously add significant bulk, and may not fit in the fixture (or may look pretty darned ugly).

A better solution may to be leave the room fixture alone and set up remote control of a floor- or counter- mounted lamp. That would provide sufficient light for you to navigate the room until you can get to the far end and turn on the overhead lights.

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider replacing the switch with a [motion-controlled/manual switch combo](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Lutron-Maestro-2-Amp-Single-Pole-Occupancy-Sensing-Switch-Light-Almond-MS-OPS2H-LA/203202140).  Walk in the room and it turns on automatically.   Turn it off manually when you go to bed.  Bonus lower energy bill if you are forgetful like me.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous remote control systems available that use a stand alone switch and a receiver that either sits in the light fixture or in a circuit box to receive the signal and control power on the line.

One example is the [LevNet](http://www.leviton.com/OA_HTML/SectionDisplay.jsp?section=38837&minisite=10251) system form Leviton. The receiver replaces your exisiting switch and a wireless switch goes wherever you choose.

A [simpler system](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Heath-Zenith-Basic-Solutions-Wireless-Switch-and-Socket-in-White/17101313) involves a screw in receiver at the fixture, but this particular one gets mixed reviews.

Search for *wireless switches* to see a wide range of solutions.

```
 Links and references are illustrative only and not an endorsement.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous products that meet this need.  You can start with a Google or product search, for example: [http://lmgtfy.com/?q=%22Wireless+Add+On+Switches%22](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=%22Wireless%20Add%20On%20Switches%22)

[image: Bl-6138-WH]

There's no problem permanently leaving the existing switch left on.  You can even get a small plastic clip that will prevent someone from accidentally switching the light off (tape never works well for this application).

CFL compatibility can be an issue with switches like these.  Many are derived from models that draw their own operating current *through* the bulb, which gives CFLs and some LEDs fits.  If you have a problem you may be forced to switch models.

Note: I recommend avoiding X10 technology at all costs.  It's slow, often unreliabile in unpredictable ways.  Everything else is better.

Comment: Why avoid X10?  Care to share your experience with it?

Comment: I don't think introducing a ground will stop the CFL/LED flicker issue.  Nothing (even low amperage devices) are allowed to use the ground as a neutral.  The device you show an image of has no ground connect anyway.

Comment: @Paul X10 is slow, unreliable, the main vendor has gone bankrupt, any noise on the line makes it unreliable.  The neutral issue has to do with a current path through the bulb (not ground, I'll fix that).

Comment: I automated my house in the 1990s with extensive use of X10.  It controlled several important aspects like the hot tub to protect from freezing, portions of the heat pump's defrost logic, and the gas fireplace to protect the house from freezing when the power was out.  X10 worked quite well.

Comment: @wallyk X10 works less well these days, due to inability to reject interference from other devices.  X10's was good in the day, it's days are past.